Pandas/Python how to insert data into a column rows based on closest values to a specified interval from a specific row
I have a dataframe containing a column of Datetime data where I have specified the rows (in a separate status column) corresponding to midpoint between the start and end of each rest cycle.
                  DateTime  status
235  2024-05-03 15:26:35.0    None
236  2024-05-03 15:26:35.4    None
237  2024-05-03 15:26:35.8    None
238  2024-05-03 15:26:36.2    None
239  2024-05-03 15:26:36.6    None
240  2024-05-03 15:26:37.0    None
241  2024-05-03 15:26:37.4    None
242  2024-05-03 15:26:37.8    None
243  2024-05-03 15:26:38.2    None
244  2024-05-03 15:26:38.6    None
245  2024-05-03 15:26:39.0  midway
246  2024-05-03 15:26:39.4    None
247  2024-05-03 15:26:39.8    None
248  2024-05-03 15:26:40.2    None
249  2024-05-03 15:26:40.6    None
250  2024-05-03 15:26:41.0    None
251  2024-05-03 15:26:41.4    None
252  2024-05-03 15:26:41.8    None
253  2024-05-03 15:26:42.2    None
254  2024-05-03 15:26:42.6    None

The rest cycle lasts 5 seconds, so the start would be 2.5 seconds before the midpoint time and the end 2.5 seconds after the midpoint time.   There is no row in the Datetime column which is exactly 2.5 seconds before or after the midpoint time so I would like to use the next closest row (regardless of whether it is longer or shorter than 2.5 seconds from the midpoint).   I want to insert data into the status column for all of the rows within the ~ 5 second span around the midpoint.
The solutions I have look at so far involve going through the dataframe row by row.  Is there a pandas vector method for completing this?
This is how I would like the dataframe to appear after this operation:
                  DateTime      status
235  2024-05-03 15:26:35.0        None
236  2024-05-03 15:26:35.4        None
237  2024-05-03 15:26:35.8        None
238  2024-05-03 15:26:36.2        None
239  2024-05-03 15:26:36.6  rest_start
240  2024-05-03 15:26:37.0        None
241  2024-05-03 15:26:37.4        rest
242  2024-05-03 15:26:37.8        rest
243  2024-05-03 15:26:38.2        rest
244  2024-05-03 15:26:38.6        rest
245  2024-05-03 15:26:39.0      midway
246  2024-05-03 15:26:39.4        rest
247  2024-05-03 15:26:39.8        rest
248  2024-05-03 15:26:40.2        rest
249  2024-05-03 15:26:40.6        rest
250  2024-05-03 15:26:41.0        rest
251  2024-05-03 15:26:41.4    rest_end
252  2024-05-03 15:26:41.8        None
253  2024-05-03 15:26:42.2        None
254  2024-05-03 15:26:42.6        None

i did try adapting some logic iterating through rows, but this defeats the purpose of using a dataframe

you can use a vectorized approach with Pandas to label the rows within the 5-second span around each midpoint. Here’s how you can do it:

Identify the midpoint rows by filtering where status == 'midway'.

For each midpoint, calculate a start and end time (2.5 seconds before and after the midpoint).

Use a mask to apply the rest cycle labels (rest_start, rest, rest_end) within the closest rows around each midpoint.


'''
import pandas as pd
# Sample data
data = {
    'DateTime': pd.to_datetime([
        '2024-05-03 15:26:35.0', '2024-05-03 15:26:35.4', '2024-05-03 15:26:35.8',
        '2024-05-03 15:26:36.2', '2024-05-03 15:26:36.6', '2024-05-03 15:26:37.0',
        '2024-05-03 15:26:37.4', '2024-05-03 15:26:37.8', '2024-05-03 15:26:38.2',
        '2024-05-03 15:26:38.6', '2024-05-03 15:26:39.0', '2024-05-03 15:26:39.4',
        '2024-05-03 15:26:39.8', '2024-05-03 15:26:40.2', '2024-05-03 15:26:40.6',
        '2024-05-03 15:26:41.0', '2024-05-03 15:26:41.4', '2024-05-03 15:26:41.8',
        '2024-05-03 15:26:42.2', '2024-05-03 15:26:42.6'
    ]),
    'status': [None] * 10 + ['midway'] + [None] * 9
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
 
# Define a time delta of 2.5 seconds
time_delta = pd.Timedelta(seconds=2.5)
 
# Find rows with midpoint status and iterate over them
midpoints = df[df['status'] == 'midway'].index
 
for midpoint in midpoints:
    midpoint_time = df.loc[midpoint, 'DateTime']
    
    # Define start and end range
    start_time = midpoint_time - time_delta
    end_time = midpoint_time + time_delta
    
    # Apply conditions to select closest rows within the range
    mask = (df['DateTime'] >= start_time) & (df['DateTime'] <= end_time)
    selected_rows = df[mask].index
    
    # Label the rows accordingly
    df.loc[selected_rows[0], 'status'] = 'rest_start'
    df.loc[selected_rows[-1], 'status'] = 'rest_end'
    df.loc[selected_rows[1:-1], 'status'] = 'rest'
 
print(df)

'''
Midpoint Identification: The midpoint rows (status == 'midway') are located and iterated over.
Range Selection: For each midpoint, a 5-second range (2.5 seconds before and after the midpoint) is established.
Row Masking: A boolean mask captures rows within this range, automatically selecting the closest rows.
Labeling: The first row in this range gets the rest_start label, the last row gets rest_end, and the remaining rows are labeled as rest.

Is this an AI answer?
